# Proving $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is order preserving

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, suppose $p_n$ denote the set of all prime divisors of $n$. Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}\{\mathbb{N}\}$ by $f(n)=p_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Show that $f$ is order preserving. Here $(\mathbb{N},\le)$ and $(\mathcal{P}\{\mathbb{N}\},\subseteq)$ are ordered sets.

So all I have to prove is that for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}, m\le n\implies f(m)\subseteq f(n)$.

Let $m=5, n=7$. Then $5\le 7$ and $f(5)=p_5=\{1,5\}, f(7)=p_7=\{1,7\}$ but $f(5)\not\subseteq f(7)$. So how is $f$ order-preserving?

**EDIT:** From the comment of J.G, $1$ is not a rime. So $f(5)=p_5=\{5\}, f(7)=p_7=\{7\}$

Comment: My guess is that the order relation in $\Bbb N$ is not “$a$ is smaller or equal to $b$”, but “$a$ divedes $b$” instead.

Comment: [$1$ is not a prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one), so $p_5=\{5\}$ etc.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in your case, the proof holds trivially. But is there any conventional way to proof this? Because $m|n\implies$ all prime divisors of $m$ will divide $n$ and hence $p_m\subseteq p_n$.

Comment: $6\le 7$ but $p_6 \not\subseteq p_7$

Comment: To prove *what*? The statement from your question or the one that I suggested?

Comment: @DavidP That is also true. So my guess is that there is something missing in the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That you suggested

Comment: If $a\mid b$, and if $p$ is a prime factor of $a$, then $p\mid a$. But then, since $a\mid b$, $p\mid b$. This proves that $f(a)\subseteq f(b)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes. So I can conclude that the question is less informative.